# Partial Updates : Query then update a row in SQL to ensure only updating modified values

Tags: sql, go, sql-update

I'm trying to update a row of a table but i can't know in advance which field will be updated.

First i was thinking i would just query the existing row then compare the old values vs the new values and only update the ones that are different, but even if very very unlikely in my use case, if someone were to update the data while in the middle of my update ( while holding the result of my -compare- query in memory/ram) i would overwrite all the he changes made after update.

Currently i'm thinking of trying to make this into a transaction that would first query then update then commit, but again it would either block all other requests or end up with the same result.

What is the proper way ( if there is any )  to only update the field i want while passing the whole "updated" object. I could prepare as many query combination as their's column and decide at runtime which query to use but it seems so messy and unrealistic that i'm sure there's another way to do that.

Edit with an example of the issue i'm trying to avoid :

original data : 
c1 = foo  c2 = bar

Back end makes a query and retrieve the row so will hold in ram 
c1 = foo c2 = bar

at the exact same time another user does the same and will hold 
c1 = foo c2 = bar

user 1 wants to update c2 to "hello"

user 2 wants to update c1 to "hi"

User 1 update query will be `UPDATE table SET c1="foo" ,c2="hello"`

User 2 update query iwll be `UPDATE table SET c1="hi" ,c2="bar"`

The user for which the query is sent first will then be overwritten by the other.

Comment: with UPDATE in SQL you explicitally declare  the column you want update ..  in the SET clause you declare  these columns ..

Comment: Are there any reasons why you don't want to set every column on update? For example what's wrong with `update t set c1=$1, c2=$2, ... where id=$n`? If in this scenario value `$1` is the same as the value in `c1`, what's the harm in doing `c1=$1`?

Comment: because it can result in overwrite if 2 updates are happening at the same time.
If another user is doing the exact same thing with different values.
If im trying to update c2 only and set c1 again with the original value of c1 and while updating someone updated c1 , i would overwrite his update an set it back.

Comment: for @scaiseEdge Indeed and i would declare all columns in my query that's not the point.
If i want to update c2 to "bar".  If i first query to get the current " state " : c1 = foo , c2=world i will hold this in RAM while doing the compare and then do update c1 = foo , c2 = bar but if at the exact same time another user updated for c1 = TEST , c2 = world one of us would overwrite the other's changes.

Comment: added concret example of the issue

Comment: One thing you could do is to have each field keep track of changes, then, have those fields that did not change produce a `nil` as the input to the query executing method, then pair that with an update-all-columns sql query but use coalesce as the value expression. i.e. `c1=COALESCE($1, c1)`, if the value passed as `$1` is `nil` it will be sent as `NULL` to the db and `COALESCE` will choose `c1` over `NULL`.

Comment: ... another solution would be to build the query based on the changed fields at runtime.

Comment: I'll look into coalesce as i'm not familiar with it, i was trying to avoid building the query at runtime since i need to do it over lots of query it's going to be quite tedious..